# How to send an Array to Jsp using Ext.Ajax.request?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've an Array in my HTML file and want to send it to a Jsp file using Ext.Ajax.request on button submit...
my code is :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'myArray',
    fields:['id','name', 'email'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"id":"1", "name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@ArrayData.com"},
        {"id":"2", "name":"Bart", "email":"bart@ArrayData.com"},
        {"id":"3", "name":"Homer", "email":"home@ArrayData.com"},
        {"id":"4", "name":"Marge", "email":"marge@ArrayData.com"}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});


Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'prac.jsp',
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: myArray,
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log('woops');
    }
});
    }
    }
});

});
```

i've got this error in Firebug:

too much recursion

return toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';

Comment: Your problem probably isn't anything to do with the ajax call, but with whatever contains `return toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';`.  Where's that?

Comment: @rob that  "toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';" is not in my code .. it is in ext-all-debug.js line no 329. i've no clue what is happening here..

Comment: where is the definition of array_edited variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've posted a wrong portion of the actual code. Really sorry for the confusion ... the working code is:::

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var array_edited=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'myArray_edited',
    fields:['id','name', 'email'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'newjsp.jsp',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {arr: array_edited},
    callback: function (options, success, response) {
    if (success) {
    var json = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
       Ext.MessageBox.alert('Add Profile Info', json.msg);
    }
    },
    //jsonData: array_edited,
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    },
    failure: function() {
        console.log('woops');
    }
});
    }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? You never posted what `myArray` or `array_edited` are.

Comment: I don't think that this is an answer for this question either. You should have edited your question before putting new things to your answer.